# dynamic assignment of a class to list

Tags: jquery, menuitem, submenu

I am writing because I have a problem of allocation of a dynamic class to a list. 
This is because you probably do not run well the sub-items. 
My code is:

```
<nav id="menu">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="fourteen columns" style="width: 765px">

        <ul>
            <li class="current">
                <a href="#storia" >ABOUT US</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#storia">STORIA</a></li>
                                        <li ><a href="#team" >TEAM</a></li>
                                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#fianco">SERVICES</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#fianco" >COMPETENZA</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#referenze">REFERENZE</a></li>

                        </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

And the Javascript:

```
//build dropdown
$("<select />").appendTo("#menu");

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
    "value"   : "",
    "text"    : "Go to..."
}).appendTo("nav select");  

// Populate dropdowns with the first menu items
$("#menu li a").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $("<option />", {
        "value"   : el.attr("href"),
        "text"    : el.text()
    }).appendTo("nav select");
});

//make responsive dropdown menu actually work           
$("nav select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

Thanks to everyone help me!

Comment: Code runs fine, what is the problem?

Comment: @epascarello To me it does not work, if I click on "About Us" assigns the class at "services", and if I click on the latter attribute is not assigned

Comment: What is the problem? Works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/6gfpv/

Comment: @JayNa In my site not WORK!! [link](http://www.struchel.com/peopledesign/def)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are just changing the position of the window rather than actually clicking the element. That is why no class is being assigned. Change the last part to the following:

```
$("nav select").change(function () {
    var link = $(this).val();
    if( link != "") //don't do anything for "Go To"
        $('#menu li a[href=' + link + ']')[0].click(); //simulate click
});
```

EDIT:
Check out the complete jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gfpv/1/